# How to open a Particular tab by default when VC loads, How to move to index Tab when child ViewController Opened in CAPSPageMenu?

Tags: ios, swift4.2, xcode10.1

I have implemented https://github.com/PageMenu/PageMenu library in **Swift 4.2**

My Screen look like below :

1.https://ibb.co/QdkFdMR

2.https://ibb.co/cksN3ww

When i click **Edit** button of `Profile Details`, i am navigating to a VC with name `DoctorPersonalEdit` by following code :

```
let personalDetail = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DoctorPersonalEdit") as! DoctorPersonalEdit
self.parentNavigationController?.pushViewController(personalDetail, animated: true)
```

till here everything works properly after that when i click **Save** button i want to go to previous page i.e 1st screenshot how can i go back to previous page. Also , when Screen loads first time i have to highlights third tab `Business Page`. Could some one help me i tried searching library but couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use this line of code

_ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried dismissing the VC ?
On your "saveBtn" IBAction do:

```
self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion:nil)
```

How did you implement the tab? Do you switch between them with a Switch Case? If that's the case, you just have to change the default value.